# deserialize json in wcf method parameter is null

Tags: c#, json, wcf, parameters, null

I have a wcf service and an angular app that sends a request to insert or update a customer. The wcf service receives the request, invokes the proper method but the method parameter value is null. I have tried with changing the WebMessageBodyStyle to Bare but then the method itself isn't even invoked. I have tried with [FromBody] attribute, both with an object and a string parameter. Both enter the method but the parameter value is still null. I'm out of ideas. Help would be appreciated.

```
        [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomerService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        bool InsertOrUpdateCustomer(Customer customer);

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Customer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public CustomerType Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String NewPassword { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual IList<CustomerLicense> CustomerLicenses { get; set; }
    }

    public enum CustomerType
    {
        Organizational = 0,
        Individual = 1
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Address
    {
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class CustomerLicense
    {
    }

    public class Service : ICustomerService
    {

        public bool InsertOrUpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            try
            {
                if (customer == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customer));
                //do work for insert/update
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below I have the request Angular app sent to the wcf service:

```html
POST http://localhost:49258/CustomerSecurityService.svc/CustomerSecurityService/InsertOrUpdateCustomer HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:49258
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 109
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost:9342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Basic c2FtZXByb2JsZW06bW9yZWNvZGU=
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:9342/index.html/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

{"Password":"passwordtest","Name":"nametest","NewPassword":"newPasswordTest","Type":1,"Email":"test@test.be"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrapped request, pack your JSON like:

```
{"customer":{"Password":"passwordtest","Name":"nametest","NewPassword":"newPasswordTest","Type":1,"Email":"test@test.be", "Addresses":"null", "CustomerLicenses":"null" }}
```